# Whenever I try to save file it gives me below error

Tags: writefile, savechanges, locked-files

Failed to save 'namste.c++': Unable to write file 'e:\Placement\DSA\Programs\namste.c++' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'e:\Placement\DSA\Programs\namste.c++')

Whenever I try to save a file in vs code it gives me this error. Try many things like checking the permission try to create a new folder and run another file but it gives me same error.

I try to save the above file after writing the code. But constantly it gives me the above error.